# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - request? Laravel

Tags: laravel, httprequest, laravel-blade

I have a problem with my request. I think I allready know why I'm getting this error but don't have any idea how to fix it...

It's about this Form in my blade:

```
{!! Form::open(['action' => 'TrickController@tags', 'class' => 'blog-form']) !!}

  @foreach($ids as $id)
    {!! Form::hidden('id[]', $id) !!}
  @endforeach

  {!! Form::label('tags', 'Tags') !!}
  {!! Form::text('name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'example, example, example']) !!}
  <br>
  {!! Form::submit('Absenden', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

To be more specific, it's because of the hidden field inside the foreach loop.
If I'm doing something wrong, my request should give me errors, but instead it gives me this error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

If I do everything correct, multiple `id`'s get passed to my controller and my whole code works. But I need the errors from my request if the user does something incorrect.

Does anybody know what I can do against it?

My request works fine if I just pass a single `id` like the following:

```
{!! Form::hidden('id', 5) !!}
```

Thanks for taking your time.

### Found a good way :) -- SOLVED CODE :

I used the serialize function on my ID array

```
$data = serialize($id_array);
```

then I passed that to my view and used it in my hidden field without a foreach at all

```
{!! Form::hidden('id', $data) !!}
```

and at the next controller function, I just used the unserialize function

```
$id = unserialize($id);
```

and got them back as an array :)

Comment: I understand it's cool to use blade syntax, but you are not forced to adopt it in any circumstance.

I'd consider using a classic `<input type="hidden">`, have you tried that way?

Comment: The error says that $ids variable isn't an array. Dump it to see it's type/value.

Comment: but If I do anything right, I pass all the ID's to my controller - as an array. But I allready fixed that :)

Answer (score 1):

The `foreach` loop is expecting you to give it something it can iterate over. I imagine the `$ids` variable you are using is sometimes not meeting this condition and you're therefore getting the error `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`.

Some points to consider to fix this issue:

Check how the variable `$ids` is getting set and consider rewriting how you initialise this variable. You could add the code which you use to initialise the variable to your question to receive some recommendations on how to change it.

Check up on your `$ids` variable before you pass it to the view by using checks using methods like `is_array($ids)` or `is_object($ids)` and perhaps initialising it as an empty array if it returns something that is not iterable.

Or you could do a combination of both points!

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've updated my question with a good way to solve my problem :) thanks anyway

Comment: You're welcome. You can add your own answer and accept it if that's the case.